# Count how many individual integers there are in a string, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

What I need is to show how many integers that are less than N that are not dividable by 2,3 or 5. I have managed to get the list of numbers that are less than N and are not divisible by 2,3 or 5 but I cannot for the life of me get Python to actually count how many integers there are.
What I have so far is

```
N = int(input("\nPlease input a Number "))
if N < 0:
    print("\nThere are no answers")
else:
    for a in range(1,N+1,2):
        if a%3 !=0:
            if a%5 !=0:
```

Comment: You can save counting them all by noticing that there is a repeating pattern of length 30 (2*3*5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
N = 20

counter = 0
for a in range(1, N):
    if a%2 and a%3 and a%5:
        counter += 1
```

The result will be in `counter` at the end of the loop. Or for a fancier version, adapted from @iCodez's answer:

```
sum(1 for x in range(1, N) if all((x%2, x%3, x%5)))
=> 6
```

Comment: Also, it's a bit tricky, but if you sum `bool` values they are converted to 0 or 1.  So this will work: `sum(all(x%2, x%3, x%5) for x in range(1, N))`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring a global variable and incrementing it?

```
i = 0

... if a % 5 != 0:
        i += 1

print i
```

Comment: came up with a list of numbers with the last number being how many integers there were but I might have done it wrong myself

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite easily using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all), and [`len`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#len):

```
>>> num = int(input(':'))
:20
>>> [x for x in range(num) if all((x%2, x%3, x%5))]
[1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
>>> len([x for x in range(num) if all((x%2, x%3, x%5))])
6
>>>
```